# Bootstrap alert message giving me unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I am working on a django project and in my html file, I have this code snippet.

```
 {% block content %} 
    {% ifequal error False %}
    <script>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <strong>Login Successful</strong>
        </div>
        window.location.href="{% url 'home' %}";
    </script>
    {% endifequal %}

    {% ifequal error True %}
    <script>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <strong>Wrong credentials! Try again</strong>
        </div>
        window.location.href="{% url 'login' %}";        </script>
    {% endifequal %}

    {% endblock content %}
```

In the console, I am getting this message:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
On line 500, it is saying. Basically, it points at the line where there is a div within the first script tags. The bootstrap alert is not showing and there is no redirection. If I put a simple alert,everything works! Any idea what is wrong?

UPDATE:
I already solved it. Did another way
Thanks !!

Comment: Inside a `<script>` tag the browser expects to see JS code, not HTML. It's not clear what you're trying to do, but what you have here clearly isn't right.

Comment: @RobinZigmond it is actually for a login page. When the user has successfully logged in, I redirect him to the home page

Comment: OK, so having had a slightly closer look, all you should need to do - to avoid the problem you're having anyway - is to move the opening `<script>` tag to *after* the `div`, just before the single line of JS code you have that does the redirect. (Although note that it's probably better to do this redirect on the server side, ie use `redirect` in your Django view.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond I just did but the alert does not appear. Actually, I do not know how to do it in the view as I want an alert and a redirection as well. :/

Comment: @RobinZigmond, should I post my code for view?

Comment: @Alpha, when you redirect to another page, it renders a different page. So, it will wipe out the alert which was on the previous page.

Comment: @Wazeed, yes I was wrongly doing it. Fixed it tho